# How to find expression, evaluate and replace in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following expressions inside a String (that comes from a text file):

```
{gender=male#his#her}
{new=true#newer#older}
```

And I would like to:

1. Find the occurences of that pattern `{variable=value#if_true#if_false}`
2. Temporarily store those variables in fields such as `variableName`, `variableValue`, `ifTrue`, `ifFalse` as `String`s.
3. Evaluate an expression based on `variableName` and `variableValue` according to local variables (like String gender = "male" and String new = "true").
4. And finally replace the pattern with `ifTrue` or `ifFalse` according to (3).

Should I use `String.replaceAll()` in some way, or how do I look for this expression and save the strings that are inside? Thanks for your help

**UPDATE**

It would be something like PHP's [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php).

**UPDATE 2**

I solved this by using `Pattern` and `Matcher` as I post as an answer below.

Comment: thanks @Rob, I've tried using replaceAll but I can't make it take the value that's inside the pattern, besides that I'm terribly loss in the way of solving this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After strugling for a while I managed to get this working using `Pattern` and `Matcher` as follows:

```
// \{variable=value#if_true#if_false\}
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("\\{") + "([\\w\\s]+)=([\\w\\s]+)#([\\w\\s]+)#([\\w\\s]+)" + Pattern.quote("\\}"));
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(doc);

// if we'll make multiple replacements we should keep an offset
int offset = 0;

// perform the search
while (matcher.find()) {
    // by default, replacement is the same expression
    String replacement = matcher.group(0);
    String field = matcher.group(1);
    String value = matcher.group(2);
    String ifTrue = matcher.group(3);
    String ifFalse = matcher.group(4);

    // verify if field is gender
    if (field.equalsIgnoreCase("Gender")) {
        replacement = value.equalsIgnoreCase("Female")?ifTrue:ifFalse;
    }

    // replace the string
    doc = doc.substring(0, matcher.start() + offset) + replacement + doc.substring(matcher.end() + offset);

    // adjust the offset
    offset += replacement.length() - matcher.group(0).length();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the strings always take this format, then `string.split('#')` is probably the way to go. This will return an array of strings in the '#' separator (e.g. "{gender=male#his#her}".split('#') = {"{gender=male", "his", "her}"}; use `substring` to remove the first and last character to get rid of the braces)

Comment: thanks for your help @Zim but this pattern would be inside a text, I'm looking for a way to find the expression, evaluate the condition and replace the entire pattern with the given ifTrue and ifFalse values.